# Unable to upgrade to 22.04 because `ubuntu-desktop' is broken after upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 22.04

I've tried to update from 20.04 to 22.04 using Software Updater. It fails when trying to create "New Software Channels". The error in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` is

```
2022-10-23 16:55:26,408 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2022-10-23 16:55:34,181 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: ubuntu-desktop'
```

For some reason `ubuntu-desktop` is not updating. `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` shows this for `ubuntu-desktop`.

```
Investigating (6) ubuntu-desktop:amd64 < 1.450.2 -> 1.481 @ii pumU NPb Ib >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 | 42.0-1ubuntu7 @ii umR >
  Considering gdm3:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gdm3:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gdm3:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5 @ii umR >
  Considering gnome-control-center:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-control-center:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-control-center:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-control-center:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umR >
  Considering gnome-shell:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-shell:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-shell:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 < 33.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42-2~fakesync1 @ii umR >
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 < none | 43-2ubuntu1 @un umH >
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 2 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 2 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 < 68ubuntu1~20.04.1 | 72~ubuntu5.22.04.1 @ii umR >
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR NPb >
  Considering ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
```

I've read previous answers and it's related to external ppa's I've installed. But from the logs I'm not able to figure out what to delete. This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
freedownloadmanager.list
freedownloadmanager.list.distUpgrade
freedownloadmanager.list.save
kgilmer-ubuntu-regolith-stable-focal.list
kgilmer-ubuntu-regolith-stable-focal.list.save
linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-focal.list
linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-focal.list.distUpgrade
linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-focal.list.save
lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list
lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list.save
megasync.list
megasync.list.distUpgrade
megasync.list.save
pipewire-debian-ubuntu-pipewire-upstream-focal.list
pipewire-debian-ubuntu-pipewire-upstream-focal.list.distUpgrade
pipewire-debian-ubuntu-pipewire-upstream-focal.list.save
regolith-linux-ubuntu-release-focal.list
regolith-linux-ubuntu-release-focal.list.distUpgrade
regolith-linux-ubuntu-release-focal.list.save
regolith.list
regolith.list.distUpgrade
regolith.list.save
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this will be very helpful.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an impressive list of third party PPA's. This gives you a system that is not standard, and thus may not be able to be upgraded.

Perhaps purging each of the PPA's, i.e., removing both the PPA and the software that came with it, may revert you to a standard system that can be updated again (provided you bring it fully up to date with a `sudo apt full-upgrade`). These could then be added after upgrade.Note that it is your responsibility to check whether it is suited for the new Ubuntu version. Some PPA's continue to work, in other cases, a dedicated PPA is available for the new version, and in some cases a suited PPA may not be available.

It may, however, be equally easy to reinstall fresh and reconfigure your system. The advantage is that you will have a clean system where old obsolete configuration is gone.

Comment: Looks like I've many hours of headache ahead of me. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

will remove the unnecessary packages. Then update to latest version using do-release-upgrade command.